# Getting QUERYSTRINGPII_REMOVED in some requests

Tags: javascript, query-string, form-submit, pii

I have developed a system in which we use captive portals to log in users to a wifi network. A couple days ago I noticed some (very few) of the form submissions I'm getting have some fields stripped out and replaced by `QUERYSTRINGPII_REMOVED`, specifically the email field.

This doesn't happen to all users logging in that network, just to some of them. And it happens in random access points (not always the same). I couldn't identify anything out of place in the network of said access points.

I haven't been able to find anything anywhere, just [an unanswered question in WebMasters stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106403/why-am-i-seeing-querystringpii-removed-in-the-query-string-of-a-lot-of-reque).

I'm not sure why this is happening. I have the suspicion it has something to do with the device itself, but in any case.. does anyone have any idea of what is going on here and how to avoid it?

To give some more info, the form submissions are made by POST on an SSL secured connection. An example body of a request would be:

```
{
    "name": "Some name",
    "QUERYSTRINGPII_REMOVED": "", // This should be the email
    "some_other_field": "value"
}
```